# How to automate mongo DB script execution in Azure CI/CD pipeline

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure, azure-devops, cicd

I have a requirement where I need to automate mongo DB script execution through Azure CI/CD pipeline as we are using Azure CI/CD for code deployment.
We want to automate Mongo DB script execution also with pipeline.

Is there any way to execute DB script through pipeline by picking script from storage account or file directory?.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found these doesn't have any built-in task to picking script from storage account or file directory.

You can choose to use powershell to [download the script to agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#download-blobs) and run it.

But I more recommend you to upload DB script to specific folder in branch. And then triggered by the folder in branch.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And how can we automate the script execution from folder in branch.